# Android translate animation move to absolute position

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, interpolation

is there a way to tell a translate animation to always move to a absolute position, instead to a position relative to the card. As far as I know, using `android:toXDelta` only moves it to a relative position. I want it to move to a absolute position (lets say width of the screen / 2 and height of the screen / 2) from every point on the screen.

My animation:

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
           android:duration="1000"
           android:fromXDelta="0"
           android:fromYDelta="0"
           android:toXDelta="-20%p"
           android:toYDelta="-20%p" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from official [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html) it is not possible from XML.
However, you can do this in your Java code. Example:

```
    view.animate().translationX(0f).translationY(0f).setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()).start();
```

`TranslationX` and `TranslationY` animates to an absolute position. There is also `TranslationXBy` an `TranslationYBy` that animate relatively.

Comment: So how would I do this in java? I heard you can use `TranslateAnimation` for it, but will it work together with my existing xml code?

Comment: Are you trying to animate a View?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to accelerate/decelerate my view using the xml code above. It works so far, but I am not able to make it move to an absolute position, instead to a position relative to the view

Comment: Edited my answer with an example.

Comment: so translationX would be the absolute translation in pixels? So if I want to animate from any position to 200 200 I would just use 200f as the param?

Comment: Yes pixels. 0,0 point is located in left upper corner. Just play with it and see how it goes.